# Is there a blog platform that renders LaTeX well?

Tags: latex

I've been using wordpress.com, but it renders LaTeX terribly! There must be a blogging platform that does a good job of this. Can someone recommend one?

Comment: Have you tried the google blogs? And do you need free, or is paid ok?

Comment: Paid is okay (well, within reason! :-)

Comment: Jekyll + kramdown + MathJax is the way I've gone for this: https://aung.uk/maths-example/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not appear to be about mathematics education.

Comment: @XanderHenderson, long before MESE existed, I was blogging about math and math education. Blogging is a way to share our knowledge, just as youtube videos are. It's definitely worthwhile (for the cause of math education) to know how to represent math well in various online arenas.

Comment: @SueVanHattum I don't disagree with you, but there is nothing in this question which distinguishes it from a question which might be asked on [academia.se] or on [math.se] or an any one of a bunch of other SE sites.  Where is the specific, mathematical, educational context?

Comment: @XanderHenderson It would also be on-topic on [softwarerecs.se] (or, technically, [wordpress.se]). That doesn't mean it's off-topic here.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 My point is not that it is off-topic here *because* it is on-topic somewhere else, but that the question lacks enough specificity to be on-topic *anywhere*.  Why are math education people the best people to answer this question, rather than math people, or TeX people, or experts at any one of several other sites on the SE network?

Comment: Not because we're the best ones to answer it, but because we want a collection of answers here that will help math educators to do their thing.

Comment: I'm biased, of course, but it's easy to see why it's on topic: Math educators are the most likely to be using math latex on popular  un-modified blogging platforms, like wordpress.com. I guess possibly mathematicians, but I expect that this would be considered even more off topic there by the above argument. At least educators and blogging platforms seem to go together....or at least they seems like it to me. And, there are already several useful answers!

Answer (score 15):

It is common to use [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/).
This is used on this StackExchange site for LaTeX-like input
(not full LaTeX of course).
MathJax is available for WordPress via plugins,
such as [JetPack](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jetpack/).

- See [Installing MathJax in
  WordPress](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/v1.0/platforms/wordpress.html).
- There is also the [Simple
  MathJax](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-mathjax/) plugin for WordPress.
- Another how-to: [How to Use MathJax on WordPress](https://yutsumura.com/mathjax-in-wordpress/).